# Downloading the latest version of a file

Tags: android, download, httpurlconnection

I'm using the following code to download a file off a webserver that I control

```
URL url = new URL("http://........");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput("true");
connection.connect();

InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
File dst = new File(".......");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len = 0;
while ((len=in.read(buffer))>0) {
    out.write(buffer,0,len);
}

connection.disconnect();
in.close();
out.close();
```

minus all the necessary try-catches. The above code works fine for downloading the file to my specific destination. It is however unable to download the latest version (e.g. if i change the file contents on the webserver)

it is as though the something is keeping some sort of cache of the file it downloaded before, and as long as the URL is the same as before, it sends back the same file. My data connection becomes active during the download so this might be the case at my service provider

what I need is some sort of way to force my code to proactively refresh the target file. I have found that the web-browser was able to do this. if I were to type in the link with the web-browser, and then subsequently run my code again, the latst version gets downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a `?time=201211261200` at the end of URL.

Comment: that did not work.. i'm currently still able to download a file that i have already deleted on the server

Comment: This aint random, it is fixed and will help only 1 time. (The first call)

Comment: @PoweRoy I mean, you should add a distinct number every time, for which the current time is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Either fix it at the server, or at the client.

Client: Try to make the URL random by adding a random value. Therefore always the latest version will be downloaded.

```
Random r = new Random();
int someValue = r.nextInt(10000);

"http://someurl" + "?t=" + someValue;
```